# How to maximise the first term and minimize the second term of this circle equation?

Tags: analysis, trigonometry, circles

I'm trying to help my dad for a DIY issue. I've asked Wolfram alpha to solve this circle equation:

[image]

And Wolfram came up with the following real solutions:

[image]

I'm just not sure what's the step-by-step solution I could follow to find these set of solutions myself?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this circle equation has infinite real solutions.

Comment: ... but only two which maximise the first square and minimise the second

Comment: Right, these are the ones I'm looking for sorry.

Comment: @tbop: obviously, the minimum value for the second square is zero. That's how you find $h$. The rest is also easy.

Comment: @Vasya I get how to minimze the second term in h, but I don't manage to find the two maxima for d. I thought this was then about computing the roots for (d+65*cos(pi/6))^2-4225/4 but I don't find the results computed by Wolframalpha.

Comment: @tbop: if $h$ is such that the second term is zero, then you just need to solve $(d+65\sqrt 3/4)^2=4225/4$ to find $d$.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram Alpha gives the solutions that maximize the first term and minimize the second.

The second term (in h) is obviously minimal where: $$h = 65/4$$

The first term (in d) is then maximized by finding the roots of the resulting equation:

$$
(d+65\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4})^2=\frac{4225}{4}
$$